# Confidence interval for boosted decision trees

Tags: r, confidence-interval, quantile-regression

I have been using Azure studio for predictions and I ended up using Boosted Decision Trees as it gave me the best results. However, I need to put some confidence on my predictions for out of sample data. I could not find any method so far to do that. One option was to use a different model ("Forest quantile regression") which gave me percentiles but if I want to have 95% and 4% percentiles, it will give me a very wide range which is not acceptable. I wonder if there is any alternative for these.

Comment: There is an R package called bartMachine(Bayesian Additive Regression Trees) that will give you prediction intervals. I am not sure it does quantile regression, though. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bartMachine/vignettes/bartMachine.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Hold out a test set and check the performance of the model on the test set.

Spoiler alert: RF often has significantly worse performance on the test set. You can mitigate this by limiting the tree complexity. If is best to use a validation set to choose the parameters like leaf size and number of splits, then finally use a test set to report the final performance.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the posters concern, how does a test set help in developing confidence intervals for predictions?

Comment: Work out the distribution of residuals across the test set. For future predictions, assume that the error in prediction is a random draw from this distribution. Your 95% and 5% error bounds are the ones found in the test set.

Comment: See my last post it can help you.